# How to bind std::filesystem::copy?

Tags: c++, c++20

I would like to bind the third argument of the std::filesystem::copy, i.e.

```
void copy( const std::filesystem::path& from,
           const std::filesystem::path& to,
           std::filesystem::copy_options options );
```

to a certain value, say std::filesystem::copy_options::none.

When I do:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
auto f1 = std::bind( fs::copy, _1, _2, fs::copy_options::none );
```

the gcc compiler (10.3.0, c++20) gives an error (see below):
What am I doing wrong?
Bertwim

```
> error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded
> function type>, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const
> std::_Placeholder<2>&, std::filesystem::copy_options)’   641 |        
> auto f2 = std::bind( fs::copy, std::placeholders::_1,
> std::placeholders::_2, fs::copy_options::none );
```

Comment: I guess there are multiple overloads of 'copy', so you have to explicitly type-cast the function pointer.

Comment: std::bind is so Jurrassic Code.  Modern C++ has lambdas!

Comment: @Eljay lambdas and `bind` were introduced at the same time so I wouldn't quite call it Jurassic.  Before generic lambdas, it was actually nicer to use bind in cases

Comment: @NathanOliver • I must have been recollecting Boost Bind.

Comment: Why do you need to `bind()` the 3-param version of `copy()` at all?  Just use the 2-param version, it already uses `fs::copy_options::none`.

Comment: Because, I want to have the third parameter optional, the "none" was just an example. My question was more generic.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::filesystem::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) is an overloaded function.  That means that it's name cannot decay into a single type since we don't know which overload you want.  You could fix that with a cast but instead of doing that you can use a lambda expression to create your wrapper like

```
auto f1 = [](const auto& from, const auto& to) {
              fs::copy(from, to, fs::copy_options::none); 
          };
```

Comment: Nathan, thanks for this answer. It solves my issue.